# How one user can access two different websites with automatic login to both different instance Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, customer, websites

I have two different instances for Magento 2. **If the user is logged in on Site1 and access it, then after the user goes to the Site2 then it should automatically be logged in for Site2.** I need that kind of functionality.

**One user can access two different Magento instance with a single site login.**

The user doesn't need to filled login details for site 2 it will automatically be logged in with same details which used for site 1.

Is there any another way or best option to manage a single account with both Magento instance? is it possible?

How can we achieve this?

Does anyone have an idea about it?

Answer (score 0):

@Utsav
By default magento customers are website specific however you can set them as global from **Stores -> Configuration -> Customers -> Customer Configuration -> Account Sharing Options -> Share Customer Accounts**

Through this setting your customers will be able to access multiple websites configured on same magento instance.

Comment: Your answer is appreciated, 
But I have two different Magento setup and I need this functionality if a user logged in on the site 1 the user can access site 2 with the same login but automatically, a user doesn't need to filled logged in details again. it should automatically be logged in.